# C input buffer bugs

Tags: c, buffer-overflow

I have this sample code:

```
typedef struct {
int num;
char name[100];
float grade;
} Student;
```

- 

```
    Student newStudent() {
         Student a;
         printf("New Student\n");
         printf("Number: ")
         scanf("%d", &a.num);

         if(a.num > 0){
             printf("Name: ");
             scanf("\n%99[^\n]", a.name);
             printf("grade: ");
             scanf("%f", &a.grade);
         }
         else {
             a.num = -1;
         }
         return a;
}
```

The way this code is confusing me for the following reasons:

1. I can easily overflow if in the first scanf I input something with spaces, i.e. 239472 8932792.
2. How should I interpret the **\n%99[^\n]** in the second scanf? I've noticed that if I remove the first **\n**, the whole input system is ruined, even if I do everything right in the first.
3. How could I built a better code so that it's overflow proof?

Comment: Your code is already overflow proof...

Comment: @Aplet123, it isn't... If for number I enter something like "3 3", then  the console will show "Name: grade:". Any input thereafter is badly formatted.

Comment: First two answers there describe problems associated with `scanf()` function and how to mitigate them in great detail: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430303/disadvantages-of-scanf

Comment: That's not an overflow, that's just input being buffered.

Comment: _"...How could I built a better code so that it's overflow proof"_  This question is answered all over this site.  Which of these have you already looked at?